# How to Get next image with my this code from same post -(wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show images in my single-content.php file. I have almost 20 to 25 images in every post. I want to print them with below code one by one. I have to change one line in code for every image for uniqueness so that's why I need to print them one by one not all in one loop.

I have code but I'm unable to add option for next image to print. I mean when I copy and paste the same code same image is printed again. So basically I need help here. How can I get next image when I paste code again and again for 20 time or 25 times to get all images. Hope I can describe my problem. (Sorry for my bad english.)

```
/* ATTACHMENT*/

  $args = array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'post_parent' => $posid,
        'post_status' => null,
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
  );

  $atts = get_children( $args );

  $tatts = count($atts);
  $i = 1;

  foreach ($atts as $at)    
      $atid = $at->ID;
      $mimg = wp_get_attachment_image_src($atid,'large');
      $msrc = $mimg[0];
      $mw = $mimg[1];
      $mh = $mimg[2];
      $atslug = $at->post_name;
      $aturl = $surl.'/'.$poslug.'/'.$atslug.'/';
      echo '  <img class="mdi" src="'.$msrc.'"   />  ';
```

In other way I need a code that can display images in my post one by one (I know I can insert images in my post, but I want to just upload images to post and my code fetch images for me as I have to apply a php code for images as above code do same the code fetch images that attached to post ) like in my file template I put code like this, for ex: my all posts has 5 images so I want code like this:

```
    <img src'<?php first-attachment-url ?>')"> 
<img src'<?php second-attachment-url ?>')">
<img src'<?php third-attachment-url ?>')">
<img src'<?php fourth-attachment-url ?>')">
<img src'<?php fifth-attachment-url ?>')">
```

Answer (score 0):

a bit modification of your code

```
<?php
            $args = array(

        'numberposts' => -1,

        'order' => 'ASC',

        'post_mime_type' => 'image',

        'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),

        'post_status' => null,

        'post_type' => 'attachment',

    );

$atts = get_children( $args );

  $tatts = count($atts);
  $i = 1;

  foreach ($atts as $at) {

      $atid = $at->ID;

      $mimg = wp_get_attachment_image_src($atid,'large');

      $msrc = $mimg[0];

      $mw = $mimg[1];

      $mh = $mimg[2];
      $atslug = $at->post_name;
      $aturl = $surl.'/'.$poslug.'/'.$atslug.'/';
        echo '  <img class="mdi" src="'.$msrc.'"   />  ';
  }  


 ?>
```

please let me know if it's like what you want or not

Comment: thanks for your help and time, but its still show the same image when i paste code again ... i want to that if i post code 2 time, codes get first 2 images attached to post if i paste code 3 time get 3 images from post. hope you got my point. thanks again

Comment: is their any possibility to achieve this in wordpress ?

Comment: sorry for my bad english.. but i just not clear enough with your question.. or maybe not just me